# Rails Tutorial: nokogiri-1.5.2 error on bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, nokogiri, railstutorial.org

After working through the RVM setup, rspec and guard sections of chapter 3 of the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages), whenever I run `bundle install` I get the following error dump:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /home/dan/.bundler/tmp/17577/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/dan/.bundler/tmp/17577/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing nokogiri (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

In the gem_make.out:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file --mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

I've been debugging for a while now and I think I'm stuck. Help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Does this help? http://rubyforge.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=4161&forum_id=4050

Comment: Does bundle install work with nokogiri commented out?

Comment: @VidurMurali: nokogiri is not in my Gemfile, just a dependency and I'm not sure which gem(s) depend on it, so I don't know how I could prevent bundle from trying to install it.

Comment: @DVG: I'm not sure if it does. I'm not at all familiar with straight Ruby (or even Rails for that matter) so it's hard to tell if that would work in this situation.

Comment: `sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev` ?

Comment: @Zabba: Thanks so much! That solved it. If you post an answer I can give you credit...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You need the header files for compiling extension modules for Ruby.

You can get the proper version for your version of ruby with:

`sudo aptitude install ruby-dev`

Comment: It should be worth noting ruby1.9.1 is actually Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: The generic solution is to use `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev`.  It will match whatever `ruby` package is in your distribution, assuming you're using Debian/Ubuntu or derivative.

Comment: @Zenexer: Thank you, your answer is actually the solution!