# Unable to install Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, nokogiri

When I run `sudo gem install nokogiri` on Ubuntu 12.1, I'm returned with this. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

```
jason@jason:~/ror/clss$ sudo gem install nokogiri
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file 
-- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5 for 
inspection. Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.5/ext/nokogiri
/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What's in the `gem_make.out` file that the error message mentions?

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: It returned with /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
 from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require'
 from extconf.rb:5:in <main>'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to install the "libxslt-dev" and "libxml2-dev" packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

The instructions are on http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

---

Update:

You need `sudo aptitude install ruby1.9.1-dev`.

Source: "[Rails Tutorial: nokogiri-1.5.2 error on bundle install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466566/rails-tutorial-nokogiri-1-5-2-error-on-bundle-install/10466866#10466866)".