# When I try to run bundler get an error:

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

```
bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using RedCloth (4.2.9) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.6) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.6) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.6) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.6) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.6) 
Using activeresource (3.2.6) 
Using bundler (1.1.4) 
Installing nokogiri (1.5.2) with native extensions 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
extconf.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... yes
checking for exsltFuncRegister() in -lexslt... yes
checking for xmlHasFeature()... yes
checking for xmlFirstElementChild()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlRelaxNGSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes 
checking for xmlSchemaSetValidStructuredErrors()... yes
checking for xmlSchemaSetParserStructuredErrors()... yes
creating Makefile

make
compiling html_sax_push_parser.c
compiling xslt_stylesheet.c
compiling html_document.c
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
xml_xpath_context.c: In function ‘xpath_generic_exception_handler’:
xml_xpath_context.c:189:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [xml_xpath_context.o] Error 1
```

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

An error occured while installing nokogiri (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.2'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Which OS are you using ? If on mac, ensure you have command line tools for xcode or install them using 'xcode-select --install'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing nokogiri - Failed to build gem native extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14019318/installing-nokogiri-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

Comment: It's a bug in 1.5.2 on Debian flavoured distros. Try 1.5.4 or up.